# Creating drop down list using Spring, Hibernate, JSP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Applications: Hibernate, Spring 3.0 MVC, JSP (used Spring forms)

Requirement: To select a table data from the database using Hibernate and display that as a drop-down list in JSP page using Spring MVC.

Code:
Hibernate / Dao code is

**Cuisine class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cuisine")
public class Cuisine {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

.. getters and setters
```

**RecipeDaoImpl class**

```
public List<Cuisine> getCuisine() {
    String hql = "SELECT id, name FROM Cuisine";
    return getSession().createQuery(hql).list();
}
```

Spring MVC

```
@Controller
public class RecipeController {
...
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String newRecipe(Map<String, Object> map) {  
        /* Get cuisine list and new object for cuisine */
        List<Cuisine> cuisines = recipeServices.getCuisine();
        System.out.println(cuisines);
        map.put("cuisineList", cuisines);
        map.put("cuisine", new Cuisine());

        return "recipes/new";
    }
```

JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<tr>
    <th><sf:label path="cuisine">Cuisine</sf:label></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><sf:select path="${cuisineList}">
             <sf:options items="${cuisine}"></sf:options>
        </sf:select></td>
    </tr>
```

On doing it, I am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property '[Cuisine [id=1, name=Continental][id=2, name=Italian]' of bean class [com.recipe.tables.Recipe]: Bean property '[Cuisine [id=1, name=Continental][id=2, name=Italian]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:729)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
```

Can someone please suggest how to fix this? I have checked couple of articles and tried to replicate them, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think jsp should be

```
<td><sf:select path="${cuisine}">
         <sf:options items="${cuisineList}" id="id" itemValue="name"></sf:options>
    </sf:select></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks.. but it is not giving value as "[id=1, name=Continental]" in the drop down box.. any way I can just get name in the JSP page?

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer.. I have added "<sf:options items="${cuisineList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />" and it worked..

Comment: I'm getting this error while doing so... `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name`, any clues?

Comment: one more error `ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag - Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name`